# How can I reference all elements in the JToken collection in a subquery

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have a method (CSOM Sharepoint Taxonomy related) that returns certain elements from subquery collection based on a certain parameter

Currently it returns only first element from the collection or the last element; however, I would like to return all elements including first and the last

I don't want to change the structure of the code, just want to modify it keeping the LINQ format

Please let me know how it could be done officially

```
    public List<JToken> GetSubTermsByTermName(string type, string termName)
    {
        var termSetTerms =
            from t in Terms
            where (string)t["type"].First == type
            select t;

        var rootTerms = termSetTerms.Where(t =>

        termSetTerms.Any(u =>
            ((string)u["label"] == (string)t["sub_class_of"].First["label"]
                && (string)t["sub_class_of"].First["label"] == termName)  ||
            ((string)u["label"] == (string)t["sub_class_of"].Last["label"]
                && (string)t["sub_class_of"].Last["label"] == termName)));

        return rootTerms.ToList<JToken>();
    }
```

Here is snippet of JSON I am trying to read

```
   "results":[
      {
         "id":"id",
         "label":"label",
         "type":[
            "my type"
         ],
         "sub_class_of":[
            {
               "id":"parentid1",
               "label":"parentlabel1"
            },
            {
               "id":"parentid2",
               "label":"parentlabel2"
            },
            {
               "id":"parentid3",
               "label":"parentlabel3"
            }
         ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you share more details? What is the structure of the JSON you are starting from?  What is the input you are passing to your method?  Given that input what JTokens do you end up with in the list versus what you want to end up with?  Examples would be great.

Comment: Well, you're using `First` and `Last`, so... Your code is very difficult to read, mostly because of over-casting and meaningless variable names... What logic are you trying to encompass with the LINQ you've written?

Comment: Thank you for you response, I just posted a JSON code snippet, I am trying to get ALL instances of the "sub_class_of" section, not just first and last

Thank you once again for your help

Comment: You've almost provided us with a [mcve], but not quite.  What are the values for `type` and `termName` that you are passing into `GetSubTermsByTermName` when the routine does not return correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I decided to change the structure of the code, later I might change it to linq join but for now it works fine

```
public List<JToken> GetSubTermsByTermName(string type, string termName)
{
    var termSetTerms =
        from t in Terms
        where (string)t["type"].First == type
        select t;

    List<JToken> subClasses = new List<JToken>();
    foreach (var rootTerm in termSetTerms)
    {
        if (rootTerm["sub_class_of"].Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach(var subClassOf in rootTerm["sub_class_of"])
            {
                if ((string)subClassOf["label"] == termName)
                {
                    subClasses.Add(rootTerm);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return subClasses;
}
```